# Python with tkinter performs too slow while moving many canvas objects at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, performance, tkinter, graphics

I have developed a piece of software using python with tkinter to basically drawing many hexagons on the canvas and move them at the same time (like a video). It works fine in case I have 1-100 of hexagons, but in case of > 1000 hexagons, it runs really slowly. I am wondering if there any possible way to speed up the performance of the program?

Comment: There are known performance issues when you have tens of thousands of objects but the code should run reasonably well with 1000 (assuming you aren't trying to move them all every millisecond) . Without seeing your code it's hard to say anything more definitive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I am trying to move all the objects at the same time with the same speed and direction, I am wondering, is there a way that I can move the whole canvas instead? That might speed up the process.

Comment: If you're wanting to move them all at once, that shouldn't be a problem. I can create 10,00 hexagons and move them all at once at a frame rate of 30fps without a problem. I think you're going to have to provide a [mcve] if you need help.

Comment: I was about to upload an example but I figured out how to fix this problem. Instead of moving every single object at the same time, I use the method canvas.xview_moveto and it worked.

Comment: xview_moveto doens't move the objects, it scrolls the canvas. Visually that might be the same thing, but the actual coordinates of the objects won't change.